# how many unique bitcoins address can be generated in one address pattern

Tags: address, address-generation

Example address prefix given below

```
12cgpRC5r7zakGBfRGf5RQfGCgTnp7K1Yb
12cgpFkDMJXdwck9YHrrFsWP8PgxXjtBS7
12cgpcjw2628NPAPMvzSWF9Vh2tcUJrpAa
12cgpDmDJnugoRHeAfief7KSiUFvNPF5MY
12cgpz1PwVesaKArAR53W3owQy32XKuuxT
```

So first 5 letters are common prefix for all address **12cgp**

Comment: Wouldn't this be something like 2^(160 - 4)( custom char vanity) = 2^156, although these aren't compressed... Not sure how it would work in that case.. 2^(34 - 4)?

Comment: So How many million address

Comment: (2^(34-5)) / (2^(33-4)), my mistake. I still don't think this is correct though.

Comment: Essentially infinite for most purposes.

Comment: So there no end for Single address
e.g my name bitcoin will be infinite, no one can crack it or regenerate my same pattern  
1Sturtxxxxxxxxxx can be infinite